# Use the EurKEY keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to used the [EurKEY](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/start.html) custom keyboard layout on my freshly installed Ubuntu.

I followed their [installation instruction](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/download.html?lang=en) and downloaded and installed the `.deb` package manually. However when I run `setxkbmap eurkey` nothing seems to change. (I test the layout by trying Alt+A to see if I get an Umlaut, but nothing happens).

It looks like there is a warning, but I wasn't able to find out anything about it:

```
$ setxkbmap eurkey -v
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+eurkey+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
```

Since I've never messed around with custom layouts and am just following installation instructions on the website I can't quite figure out how to find or fix the problem myself.

I've also tried going to the settings and changing the layout there, but unless it has a different name, I can't seem to find the layout in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at that `eurkey.deb` file, and I don't like it. At installation it edits files belonging to the `xkb-data` package, and that's bad practice.

And the use of that `.deb` file is also unnecessary. This is what you should have done:

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package if it's not already installed.

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  ```
- Open **Tweaks**, select *Keyboard & Mouse*, and enable "Show Extended Input Sources".
- Log out and log in again.
- Go to *Settings -> Keyboard*, click the + button, select *English (United States)*, and then you can pick the *EurKEY (US)* keyboard layout.

To clean up from your attempt to follow that other instruction, I recommend that you run these commands:

```
sudo apt purge eurkey
sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I tried following your instructions (Keyborad layouts are under "Region & Language"), but I don't have EurKEY listed under "Input Sources" despite having extended input sources enabled in Gnome-Tweaks.

Comment: @Alex_M: Did you log out?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have it working now. It only works if I add German as first Input source, and EurKey as second. As soon as I remove German it stops working. Really weird behavior.

Comment: @Alex_M: That's too complicated to discuss in comments only. Please submit a new question.